Issue with Amazon SP-API putListingsItems call: payload is invalid
I'm attempting to list an offer for a product that already exists in the Amazon catalog. I've completed all the necessary steps to gather all the information required to make this call. However, when I try to execute it via Postman, I receive the following response:
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "InvalidInput",
            "message": "The provided payload is invalid.",
            "details": ""
        }
    ]
}

My endpoint URL is: https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/listings/2021-08-01/items/{{sellerId}}/1031300?marketplaceIds={{marketplaceId}}
My method is PUT, and my body is set to raw(JSON):
{
  "productType": "PRODUCT",
  "requirements": "LISTING_OFFER_ONLY",
  "attributes": {
        "merchant_suggested_asin": [
            {
                "value" : "B09K6F1W42",
                "marketplace_id": "{{marketplaceId}}"
            }
        ],
        "condition_type": [
            {
                "value": "new_new",
                "marketplace_id": "{{marketplaceId}}"
            }
        ],
        "purchasable_offer":[
            {
                "currency": "EUR",
                "our_price": {
                  "schedule": [
                    {
                      "value_with_tax": "100.00"
                    }
                  ]
                },
               "marketplace_id": "{{marketplaceId}}"
            }
        ],
        "fulfillment_availability": [
            {
                "fulfillment_channel_code": "DEFAULT",
                "quantity": "1",
                "is_inventory_available": false
            }
        ]
    }
}


I managed to execute the call and receive the status ACCEPTED. Unfortunately, not with all desired attributes. I removed the 'purchasable_offer' and 'fulfillment_availability' attributes from the payload, and the call was successful. The price and quantity can then be adjusted through a patch.

A few issues with your payload:

In fulfillment_availability, the is_inventory_available and quantity fields are mutually exclusive. Pick one, either you always have inventory available or tell Amazon how much inventory you have.
In fulfillment_availability, quantity should be an integer and not a string.
In purchasable_offer, our_price should be a list, not a struct.
In purchasable_offer, value_with_tax should be an integer.

You can use the JSON Schema returned by the Amazon Product Type Definitions  API and a JSON Schema validator (example) to find and fix all of these issues before you call putListingsItems.
